# Orion Context Broker Timezone

Tags: fiware-orion

All my entities have time zone set to:  "timezone": "Europe/Rome", but TimeInstant reports 2 hours delay.

Answer (score 1):

NGSIv2 implements the `DateTime` attribute type, as described in the "Special attribute types" of the [NGSIv2 specification document](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/):

> DateTime: identifies dates, in ISO8601 format. These attributes can be used with the query operators greater-than, less-than, greater-or-equal, less-or-equal and range. For instance (only the referred entity attribute is shown):

```
  "timestamp": {
    "value": "2017-06-17T07:21:24.238Z",
    "type: "DateTime"
  }
```

At the present moment (it may change in a next version), Orion doesn't uses timezones. Thus, if your application needs it, your application should be the one implementing timezone-awareness.

However, note that Orion Context Broker doesn't provide special treatment to attributes based on name. I mean, the name of the attribute could be `TimeInstant` or any other.

**EDIT**: Orion timezone support will improve in version 1.6.0. That version will support timezone interpretation at creation/update time (so you can use for example `2017-06-17T07:21:24.238Z` and `2017-06-17T08:21:24.238+0100` meaning the same). However, in order to set a common ground for clients accesing to the same entities from different timezones (as @LeonanCarvalho mentions) date time retrieval is in UTC/Zulu, no matter how it was stored.

Comment: If your application can be used in regions with different time zones, it is a good practice to use UTC time and you work on time conversion on user-end-interface.

Comment: Answer has been edited, to include information regarding Orion 1.6.0 to come.